# Viewing a dynamically-allocated array with the Xcode debugger?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gdb

Let's say I have an array in C++:

```
double* velocity = new double[100];
```

Using the GDB command line, I can view this array with the command:

```
> print *velocity @ 100
```

and it will print a nicely-formatted list of all the double values inside the array.

However, when using the Xcode debugger, the most it will do is treat this as a pointer to a single double value, and display velocity[0] in the variable list.

This makes it a real PITA to debug programs that contain large dynamically allocated array.  There has got to be some way to tell Xcode "This is a pointer to an array of length 100", and have it display the thing as such.  Anyone know what it is?

Comment: You mean in the debug console when you break right?  XCode 4.3 seems to support it.  Thanks for the tip off!

Comment: even if I type "print *velocity @ 100" or "print *velocity @ 100;" or "p *velocity @ 100;" in the debugger console, it won't print and give this error:
error: warningL expression result unused
error: expected ';' after expression
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Any hint? Thanks!

Comment: @Zennichimaro XCode uses lldb, not gdb. The equivalent would be `p *(double( * )[100])velocity`. From this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062173/lldb-equivalent-of-gdbs-operator-in-xcode-4-1

Comment: With this original question being 7 years old, I would've figured that this issue would've been one that would've been solved now, but I can't seem to find a definitive answer.  I'm using the latest version of Xcode (7.3.1) and I'm unable to see all the contents of an array that is using a pointer to point at it.  Any better workarounds in 2016?

Comment: @joe_04_04 it's supported now, see my answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use gdb syntax as expressions:

1. Use Run/Show/Expressions... menu to show the expressions window
2. Enter `'*velocity @ 100'` at the bottom of the window (Expression:)

Answer (score 37):

I think that my answer will be a good addition for the old one.

New versions of Xcode use `lldb` debugger as default tool instead of `gdb`.

According this [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/Introduction.html):

> With the release of Xcode 5, the LLDB debugger becomes the foundation for the debugging experience on OS X.

So for Xcode since version 5 and up I use this `lldb` command:

```
memory read -t int -c8 `array_name`
```

where:
`8` - the number of elements in array
`array_name` - the name of array
`int` - the type of array

The result of execution of this command will be something like this:

```
(lldb) memory read -t int -c8 array
(int) 0x7fff5fbff870 = 7
(int) 0x7fff5fbff874 = 6
(int) 0x7fff5fbff878 = 9
(int) 0x7fff5fbff87c = 10
(int) 0x7fff5fbff880 = 1
(int) 0x7fff5fbff884 = 8
(int) 0x7fff5fbff888 = 4
(int) 0x7fff5fbff88c = 3
```

Comment: If the name of your array happens to be all hex values, such as ABC, xcode will attempt to read values starting from address 0xABC. You can work around this by supplying '0 + ABC' instead (including quotes)

Answer (score 18):

As of Xcode 10, you can right-click `velocity`, choose "View value as..." and then "Custom Type". Then cast it to `(double(&)[100]) *velocity` and display the array in the GUI.

Comment: This works! I think since Xcode 10, this should be marked as the answer.

Comment: Well, C++ has always been the unwanted child in XCode.

Comment: The syntax is very picky. `(double(&)[100]) *velocity)` works, but `(double&[100]) *velocity` doesn't

Answer (score -3):

No unfortunately the GUI is limited and you will need to blend in a good mix of GDB magic to get things done.

Comment: See [this other answer relating to Xcode 10 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56799662/1967396) which suggests that this answer is no longer useful / valid.