# How to view contents of buffer using Xcode 4.X or lldb

Tags: xcode, lldb

I have a pointer to a buffer containing multiple doubles. Can I use Xcode or lldb to view the values of the doubles stored in the buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to gdb rather than lldb it's much easier to print out the contents of arrays, e.g. in the console:

```
(gdb) p *my_double_ptr@16
```

If `my_double_ptr` is a pointer to double then the above command will print the first 16 doubles at the address pointed to by `my_double_ptr`.

You can do this with lldb also but it's much less straightforward - see this question on SO: [LLDB equivalent of GDB's '@' operator in Xcode 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062173/lldb-equivalent-of-gdbs-operator-in-xcode-4-1).