# Printing an array slice in LLDB

Tags: c, lldb

Is there a way to print an array slice in LLDB? For example, I have a C array of ints, and I want to see elements 3-5. I'm looking for something like `p arr[3..5]`, but I cannot find the correct syntax.

Comment: Have a look at the various answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062173/lldb-equivalent-of-gdbs-operator-in-xcode-4-1.

Answer (score 1):

[`parray`](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html#examining-variables), which takes a length and an array, will print an array. To print just a slice, offset the pointer and shorten the length:

```
parray 3 p+3
```