# How can I easily show multiple values from a pointer in the Visual Studio Code debugger?

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, lldb

According to the answers on this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972511/view-array-in-visual-studio-debugger), in Visual Studio, the debugger watch window can show multiple values of an array by using this syntax: `arrName,20`.

Is there a similar way to easily show multiple values from a pointer and the following memory addresses in the Visual Studio Code debugger?

As an example, here is the struct I'm working with:

```
struct student *students = malloc(NUM_STUDENTS * sizeof *students);
```

I can show individual values using `students[idx]`, but trying to use the given Visual Studio syntax doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: If you're programming in C then please don't add unrelated language tags.

Comment: As for your problem, do you really have an *array*, or a *pointer* to the first element of an array?

Comment: It is a pointer to the first element of the array. I will edit the post to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

you can use *some_pointer@3 in vs code monitor to show the value that pointer pointed.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are asking the Visual Studio -> lldb version of this gdb -> lldb question:

[View array in LLDB: equivalent of GDB's '@' operator in Xcode 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062173/view-array-in-lldb-equivalent-of-gdbs-operator-in-xcode-4-1/11282010#11282010)

There are a bunch of "by hand" answers in that question, which were necessary at the time the question was asked, but for the past couple of years lldb has had built-in functionality for this (which is given in one of the answers):

```
(lldb) parray 20 <Expression resulting in a pointer to your array>
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. First of all there's a type (should be `parray` rather than `parry`). Second, you can use this command in the Debug Console tab of VS Code (when the debugger is lldb, evidently), but this doesn't help with watching an array in the watch window.