# Format the output of parray command in lldb console in mac

Tags: xcode, debugging, formatting, lldb

I am displaying an array (a pointer inside a structure, with the array size being defined by a calloc) using the lldb parray command [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38964008/1693203)

This shows me the value of the array in the following format:

```
(float *) $0 = 0x123456789 {  
 (float) [0] = 0.0012   
 (float) [1] = 0.123456   
 (float) [2] = 0.0012   
 (float) [3] = 0.123456   
 .  
 .  
 .
```

I would like to only display the array's values

```
0.0012   
0.123456    
0.0012   
0.123456    
.  
.  
.
```

How do I do this is the lldb console? I am using objective-c.

Also, is it possible to only display a range of values (such as from the 100th to the 150th element)?

Answer (score 2):

The `expr` command doesn't have controls over whether to print the name/type of the subelements of an aggregate object.  `parray` is just a particular use of the `expr` command.  So you can't do this with the built-in commands.

You could pretty easily write a python-based command to dump the output of an array however you would like.

Also feel free to file an enhancement request with http://bugs.llvm.org to add such an option.

You can sort of display ranges by doing:

```
(lldb) parray 4 &array[10]
(int *) $2 = 0x0000000100300218 {
  (int) [0] = 10
  (int) [1] = 11
  (int) [2] = 12
  (int) [3] = 13
(lldb)
```

Of course the numbering is off (but you didn't want to see that anyway...)

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. Would you mind having a look at my other question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331618/lldb-python-basic-print-value-of-a-global-array-while-inside-a-breakpoint-in-a?noredirect=1&lq=1