# C - How to view pointer to array of strings as array in Xcode's debugger

Tags: c, xcode, debugging, lldb

So I have `char **sentence` with `sentence[0] = string0, sentence[1] = string1`, etc. Is there a way I can print the entire array in lldb? So that it shows up as `{string0, string1, ...}`

Comment: What if there are a thousand strings in the array? Do you want them all to display?

Comment: I don't know C, but have you tried `po sentence`?

Comment: `po` calls class-implemented (in process) description methods.  For instance in ObjC they call either `description` or `debugDescription` methods.  C (and C++) data types have no convention for providing string descriptions of themselves, so po won't do anything more than `print` or `frame var` for C and C++ datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in:

[View array in LLDB: equivalent of GDB's '@' operator in Xcode 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062173/view-array-in-lldb-equivalent-of-gdbs-operator-in-xcode-4-1/38964008#38964008)

particularly, you can use the `parray` command in any recent lldb.

There isn't a way to do this in the Xcode Locals view, but you can do this in the Xcode Debugger Console.