# When debugging xcode, how can I see the value of an array of pointers?

Tags: xcode

[image: 1]

I can't see the value of the pointer array in the debugging window as pictured. I have to go down to the main function to see the array values. Is there a way to see the array values ​​in the function?

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26303375/1271826, you can use `parray` at the `(lldb)` prompt:

```
(lldb) parray 50 arr
(int *) $36 = 0x00007ff7bfeff280 {
  (int) [0] = 5
  (int) [1] = 10
  (int) [2] = 1
  (int) [3] = 4
  (int) [4] = 3
  (int) [5] = 7
  ...
```

Or you can manually add an expression `*(int(*)[50])arr` in the “variables view”:

[image]

Probably needless to say, but you can also `p *(int(*)[50])arr` at the `(lldb)` prompt.